# Python urllib different outcome in firefox

Tags: python, firefox, user-agent, urllib

I´m trying to programm a webcrawler for the message board of an austrian newspaper called derstandard.at. I´m interested in the interactions an would like to do a network analysis of the users. 
I was able to retrieve everything I wanted but when in comes to change the message boards page it simply doesn't work.

Using firefox I can simply access the pages I want by changing one number in the url for example page 5

http://derstandard.at/1345164506806/Umfrage-FPOe-auf-tiefstem-Stand-seit-mehr-als-zwei-Jahren?seite=5#forumstart

when I try to access this out of my python script I alway get page 1.

First I thought this was because of my user agent but I changed it to my firefox user agent and still get allways page 1. why ist this?

here is the relevant code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

from urllib import FancyURLopener
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1'

f_open=MyOpener()

page=BeautifulSoup(f_open.open('http://derstandard.at/1345164506806/Umfrage-FPOe-auf-tiefstem-Stand-seit-mehr-als-zwei-Jahren?seite=5#forumstart'))
```

print page

Comment: because everything here: `www.blahblah.com/blahblah` is getting you an html page, but once you put `www.blahblah.com/blahblah?something` you are running code on that html, i dont know in this case if its java or php or something else, but the reason it works in your browser is because there it supports the code, your code however, does not know how to deal with that, it just gets the first result it can.

Comment: @InbarRose that would be correct if it was javascript, however it is a normal GET request for the full page without javascript. No browser understandts php or anything else. That is not the reason for the error.

Comment: maybe it is the "#" i heard it can cause errors sometimes, put a `r` at the start of your search string. like `r'http://derstandard.at/1345164506806/Umfrage-FPOe-auf-tiefstem-Stand-seit-mehr-als-zwei-Jahren?seite=5#forumstart'`

Comment: @Inbar Rose thank you! the # actually was the problem. the r didn't help but I simply left #forumstart out and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to OP. my comment to him solved the problem.

my comment:

> maybe it is the "#" i heard it can cause errors sometimes, put a r at
>   the start of your search string. like
>   r'http://derstandard.at/1345164506806/Umfrage-FPOe-auf-tiefstem-Stand-seit-mehr‌​-als-zwei-Jahren?seite=5#forumstart'

so it seems it was a simple mistake.